# set git user name and email after ssh login on remote with one local user

Tags: git, bash, ssh

I would like to do the following, which works with the `--global` flag, however I need to do it on an on session basis, as more than one person might be working on the remote machine at a time, and hence it is important that the commits are annotated with the correct name.

`ssh root@host -t "git config --ONLY_FOR_CURRENT_SESSION user.name 'Max Payne'; git config --ONLY_FOR_CURRENT_SESSION user.email 'max@payne.com'; bash"`

so basically I want to:

1. use ssh to login to remote machine
2. pass a command that will set my git user.name and user.email for the current session

Comment: I don't think there's such a feature because it won't make sense - when you SSH in the user is already determined ($USER) and a git config (global or not) is stored in that user's home folder. If everyone is using the same user git wouldn't know what to do, and that's unsafe in any case. Multiple users can work on the same repo without using the same credentials anyway, I don't see a use for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can ssh in to the machine, you can also clone the repository and simply work locally, and that is usually the way to go.

That said, if you insist on working this way, you *can*, rather than setting up configuration files (which are necessarily shared between separate sessions, since the file system itself is also shared between separate sessions), set numerous *environment variables* as described in [the top-level `git` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html).  These include `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`, `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`, and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`, which are further described in [the `git commit-tree` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit-tree.html).

Environment variables are inherited from parent processes to child processes.  They do not cross the boundary in the other direction, i.e., no child process can affect its parent's environment data.  For this reason all environment-setting commands are (must be) built in to the shell.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for :-) working locally is not an option in this case